# Vulkan:VMA(Vulkan Memory Allocator) cannot be used NVIDIA's GPU

Tags: c++, visual-studio, vulkan

I installed VMA(Vulkan Memory Allocator) and VMA samples.But samples can't work.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLJiw.png)

This is the error that occurred at that time.

Vulkan Memory Allocator Sample 3.0.1
Vulkan API version used: 1.3
physicalDeviceProperties:
driverVersion: 0x88904000
vendorID: 0x10DE (NVIDIA)
deviceID: 0x1E89
deviceType: 2 (DISCRETE_GPU)
deviceName: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2060
limits:
maxMemoryAllocationCount: 4096
bufferImageGranularity: 1024 B
nonCoherentAtomSize: 64 B
physicalDeviceVulkan11Properties:
maxMemoryAllocationSize: 4292870144 B (4.00 GB)
physicalDeviceVulkan12Properties:
driverID: 4 (NVIDIA_PROPRIETARY)
driverName: NVIDIA
driverInfo: 546.65

MEMORY HEAPS:
heapCount=3, typeCount=5
Heap 0: 6247415808 B (5.82 GB) DEVICE_LOCAL
Type 1: DEVICE_LOCAL
Heap 1: 25648566272 B (23.89 GB)
Type 0:
Type 2: HOST_VISIBLE, HOST_COHERENT
Type 3: HOST_VISIBLE, HOST_COHERENT, HOST_CACHED
Heap 2: 224395264 B (214.00 MB) DEVICE_LOCAL
Type 4: DEVICE_LOCAL, HOST_VISIBLE, HOST_COHERENT

Conclusions:

- 2 heaps are DEVICE_LOCAL, total 6.03 GB.
- 2 heaps are HOST_VISIBLE, total 24.10 GB.
- 1 heaps are DEVICE_LOCAL and HOST_VISIBLE, total 214.00 MB.
- No types are HOST_VISIBLE but not HOST_COHERENT.
- 1 types are not DEVICE_LOCAL and not HOST_VISIBLE.
- No types are AMD-specific DEVICE_COHERENT or DEVICE_UNCACHED.
- No types are LAZILY_ALLOCATED.
- A buffer with VERTEX_BUFFER usage can be created in some non-DEVICE_LOCAL type.
- An image with OPTIMAL tiling and SAMPLED usage can be created in some non-DEVICE_LOCAL type.

Enabled extensions and features:
Validation layer: 1
Sparse binding: 1
VK_EXT_memory_budget: 1
VK_AMD_device_coherent_memory: 0
bufferDeviceAddress: 1
VK_EXT_memory_priority: 1

Assertion failed: file.is_open(), file C:\Users\usr\VulkanMemoryAllocator\src\VulkanSample.cpp, line 296

I installed  Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015, 2017 and 2019, "x64" as written in this URL.
https://github.com/GPUOpen-LibrariesAndSDKs/VulkanMemoryAllocator

Environment
OS:Windows 11
IDE:VisualStudio 2022
GPU:NVIDIA RTX 2060
Driver Version:546.65
Vulkan SDK Version:1.3.275.0

Nvidia's driver updated

Comment: The assertion is literally telling you the file and line of the error. What file failed to open? Does the resource it's pointing at exist on your file system?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your comment.
This question has been resolved.

The cause was that I had not passed the path to the shader file that I was accessing in the program.